# Relaxed Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let ${p_1,p_2,\ldots \in [0,1]}$ be a sequence such that ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n = +\infty}$. Show that there exist a sequence of events ${E_1,E_2,\dots}$ modeled by some probability space ${\Omega}$, such that ${{\bf P}(E_n)=p_n}$ for all ${n}$, and such that almost surely infinitely many of the ${E_n}$ occur. Thus we see that the hypothesis ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\bf P}(E_n) < \infty}$ in the Borel-Cantelli lemma cannot be relaxed.

At first I thought of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the unit interval with the lebesgue measure, then define $E_n := [0, p_n]$ for each $n$. But this seems not to work, any hint will be appreciated

Comment: The conclusion of this does not make any sense!! Anyways, just take $X_i \sim \mathcal U[0,1]$ i.i.d and conclude with the second bc lemma.

Comment: Use intervals like $[0,p_1], [p_1,p_1+p_2],[p_1+p_2,p_1+p_2+p_3], \dots$ where you wrap around from $1$ to $0$.  That is, in $[0,1]$ identify the endpoints to get a circle.

Comment: @Andrew This is part of a series of notes on introductory probability given in Tao' blog, this is  Exercise 21 in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/03/275a-notes-1-integration-and-expectation/comment-page-1/#comment-680919. In particular, the second BC has not been derived at this point.

Comment: @GEdgar: This is what I had in mind as well. i.e. If the sum of the probability is infinite, one should be able to cover $[0, 1]$ with arbitrary thickness.

Comment: @KKslider: Please edit your question to cite the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the following easy lemma:

> Suppose we have *finitely* many probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_N$ with $p_1 + \dots + p_N \ge 1$.  Then on some reasonable probability space such as $[0,1]$ (i.e. one $U(0,1)$ random variable), there exist events $E_1, \dots, E_N$ such that $P(E_n) = p_n$ and $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N E_n\right)=1$.  That is, almost surely, at least one of the $E_n$ happens.

Now given an infinite sequence with $\sum p_n = +\infty$, we can partition it into infinitely many finite sets, each of which has a sum of at least 1.  Apply the lemma to each set and conclude.